# Selecting distinct rows but always select the last one

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to query a `StorageDetails` table with distinct `RailcarNumber` columns. And where the `RailcarNumber` is duplicated, I only want the most recent one.

I've tried something like this:

```
var details = DbContext.StorageDetails
    .Where(d => railcars.Contains(d.RailcarNumber))
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
    .GroupBy(d => d.RailcarNumber)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        RailcarNumber = g.Key,
        Details = g.First()
    })
    .ToList();
```

But it complains about the referene to `First()`.

> The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (s.RailcarNumber),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: StorageDetail
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> )
> )
> .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I'm not sure how else I'd do what I need. `Distinct()` doesn't seem to have any options about which one it chooses.

Comment: Which First method are you using? It doesn't look like LINQ First because it takes a parameter, is that a custom method?

Comment: @SelmanGenç: Sorry, that was left over from trying `Take(1)`.

Comment: Try adding .AsEnumerable after GroupBy, the Select part of the query will be evaluated in memory instead of the DB.

Comment: @JonathanWood it is unable to convert that to SQL.Add a As Enumerable after the grouping and pull the projection from memory

Comment: @Nkosi: Calling `AsEnumerable()` will bring down all matching rows, which is more than I need. I know SQL Server can do subqueries. It seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: I assume you are using EF Core 3.1 based on the error message, which has very real difficulty translating `GroupBy` to SQL. There is some intent to improve its ability in newer releases now. How many entries would you be pulling down given you are filtering to match `railcars`?

Comment: @SelmanGenç EF Core 3.1 can't translate a naked `GroupBy` to SQL - you must have a projection that includes an aggregate method - this is a limitation of SQL as well. Unfortunately `First` is not an aggregate method for EF Core 3.1.

Comment: @NetMage: Are you saying you think older versions of EF were better at translating group by?

Comment: Every version is quite different. EF Core 2.x would silently switch to client side evaluation  when SQL translation wasn't possible, with possibly horrendous unexpected results (e.g. pulling over the entire database). EF Framework 6.x has many more years of work and would translate this query (with `FirstOrDefault)` into a `OUTER APPLY`.  LINQ to SQL would translate into one query to get the group keys and then one query per key to get the first row.

Comment: @NetMage: Wow, I would hate it pulling to client side without my direction or knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF Core 3.1, you can change the query from an `OrderByDescending().First()` to a `GroupBy().Max().Contains()` and get a single SQL query:

```
var sdIDs = DbContext.StorageDetails
              .Where(sd => railcars.Contains(sd.RailcarNumber))
              .GroupBy(sd => sd.RailcarNumber)
              .Select(sdg => sdg.Max(sd => sd.Id));

var details = DbContext.StorageDetails
                .Where(sd => sdIDs.Contains(sd.Id))
                .Select(sd => new {
                    sd.RailcarNumber,
                    Details = sd
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Probably the best I can do. Thanks. One question: this is two trips to the database, right? Is the first query executed when it's encountered in the second query?

Comment: @JonathanWood That is a trip for each row in the second plus the second.

Comment: @Nkosi: I believe this would be two trips. Entity Framework seems to be able to handle the `Contains()` clause using `IN`. What makes you say it would be a trip for each row? Anyway, I've added `ToList()` to both queries, so it should be two queries now.

Comment: @JonathanWood I was seeing the contains being invoked for each Id, but if EF can translate that then I stand corrected. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: @JonathanWood In LINQPad with EF 3.1, I see one query because the subquery `sdIDs` isn't instantiated, so the `details` query translates it to SQL as a subquery of the main query.

Comment: @NetMage: Cool. Guess I should remove my two calls to `ToList()` then.

Comment: @JonathanWood Depending on what you are going to do with it, the one on `details` might be needed.

Comment: @NetMage: Yes, I removed it for the first query and it seems to work just fine. Thanks again!